passing dynamic values to stripe checkout
I'm facing an issue with passing values in stripe checkout, I want to pass my shopping cart object to stripe checkout that's in my mongodb database. I tried finding my cart.products array and passing that in, but I get errors. Can someone please tell me what I'm missing or doing wrong, I'm passing the array in a structure of how Stripe likes it to be. If there is any more information that you need I'd be happy to send it.
Here is my code
app.js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const stripe = require('stripe')(stripeSecretKey);
const User = require('./models/users');
var Cart = require('./models/cart');

app.post('/create-checkout-session', async (req, res) => {
const owner = req.user.id;
const user = await User.findById(owner);
const cart = await Cart.findOne({user: user});
console.log(cart.products);
// console.log(req.session.cart);//undefined
console.log(req.session);

const productsList = [];
for (let i = 0; i < cart.products.length; i++) {
productName = cart.products[i].name;
console.log(productName);
image_url = cart.products[i].image;
price = cart.products[i].price;console.log(price);
id = cart.products[i].id;
console.log(id);
quantity = cart.products[i].quantity;

productsList.push({productName, price, id, quantity})
console.log(productsList)}

const items = productsList.map((product) => {
return {
price_data: {
    currency: 'usd',
    product_data: {
        name: productName,
},
        unit_amount: product.price,
},
        quantity: product.quantity,
}
});
console.log(items)

try {
const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
payment_method_types: ['card'],
mode: 'payment',
line_items: items,
success_url: ${process.env.SERVER_URL}/success.html,
cancel_url: ${process.env.SERVER_URL}/cancel.html})
res.json({url: session.url})
} catch(e) {
res.status(500).json({error: e.message})
}// res.redirect(303, session.url);});`

I have created an array that is in the form of price_data, and product_data, to pass in line_items, but I get errors like invalid string, unable to read map of undefined, etc.
console.log results
Invalid string: {:quantity=>"1", :id=>"65b80e868dc64e9eee697279", :productName=>"Black Mug", :price=>"2999"}

terminal results
[   {     price_data: { currency: 'usd', product_data: [Object], unit_amount: 2999 },     quantity: 1   },   {     price_data: { currency: 'usd', product_data: [Object], unit_amount: 2999 },     quantity: 2   },   {     price_data: { currency: 'usd', product_data: [Object], unit_amount: 3999 },     quantity: 4   },   {     price_data: { currency: 'usd', product_data: [Object], unit_amount: 3499 },     quantity: 2   },   {     price_data: { currency: 'usd', product_data: [Object], unit_amount: 4999 },     quantity: 2   },   {     price_data: { currency: 'usd', product_data: [Object], unit_amount: 4999 },     quantity: 1   } ] 
so I am able to pass items when I pass them in manually but unable to dynamically insert the array. thank you


name: productName shouldn't that be name: product.productName ?

product.name should be a string, but the error showed that your system passed the value as an object. I'd recommend double checking your code to ensure that product.name is set a string instead of an object.

@Lucky2501 thank you for pointing that out, I have made the corrections.

@yuting thank you for your help I have placed the name attribute in a template literal and it worked!
